# When I have an interrupted boot process, it shows a text-based Xubuntu splash screen. How can I change this?

Tags: grub2, xubuntu, screen, plymouth

A while ago when booting up Ubuntu 12.04 I had accidentally turned off my computer. It showed the grub screen and instead of the normal Ubuntu boot-up screen, it showed what was looking like a text version of the Plymouth boot-up screen, except it said Xubuntu 12.04 instead of Ubuntu 12.04 and it had a black background.

When booting up normally without interruptions, it shows the purple Ubuntu boot-up screen, like it should.

I am wondering why it would show a different 'text-based' Xubuntu splash screen when I accidentally powered off mid-boot, as opposed to the normal Ubuntu splash screen that it shows when there are no interruptions.

I have installed xubuntu-desktop once, but it's weird that it shows a different splash screen than normal.

Is there any way to change that back to normal or make it say Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it myself!

```
sudo update-alternatives --config text.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -u
```